# Convert 2D Array to STL

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib

I have 2D array of int elements. This array represent heights, Is it possible to convert this to a .stl file using python?

```
for i in range(100):
    for j in range(100):
        y[i, j] = randint(100, 255)
```

Comment: have you looked into https://pypi.org/project/numpy-stl/ or something similar?

Comment: STL is triangle (facet) based. What are your triangles?

Comment: Why aren't you doing `np.random.randint(100, 255, size=(100, 100))`?